# Infinite image Scroll

Tags: java, android, image, scroll

I want realize a particular app in which you can scroll an image (background) infinitely. How can i do?

For example, my .xml is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/wallpaper" >
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For infinite scroll you can use CWAC MergeAdapter. Here you can read what it is and how it works: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge